# Get last day in month of time.Time

Tags: time, go

When I have a `time.Time`:

```
// January, 29th
t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2016-01-29")
```

How can I get a `time.Time` which represents January 31st? This example is trivial, but when there's a date in February, the last day might be 28th or 29th.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> [func Date](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date)
>
> ```
> func Date(year int, month Month, day, hour, min, sec, nsec int, loc *Location) Time
> ```
>
> Date returns the Time corresponding to
>
> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss + nsec nanoseconds
>
> in the appropriate zone for that time in the given location.
>
> The month, day, hour, min, sec, and nsec values may be outside their
>   usual ranges and will be normalized during the conversion. For
>   example, October 32 converts to November 1.

For example, normalizing a date,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // January, 29th
    t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2016-01-29")
    fmt.Println(t.Date())
    // January, 31st
    y,m,_ := t.Date()
    lastday:= time.Date(y,m+1,0,0,0,0,0,time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(lastday.Date())
}
```

Output:

```
2016 January 29
2016 January 31
```

Comment: Wasn't obvious at first, that this solution was using the "0th" day of a month - and after normalization - effectively minus one day and lands on the previous month. Nice trick!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function yourself, maybe something like this:

```
func daysInMonth(month, year int) int {
    switch time.Month(month) {
    case time.April, time.June, time.September, time.November:
        return 30
    case time.February:
        if year%4 == 0 && (year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0) { // leap year
            return 29
        }
        return 28
    default: 
    return 31
    }
}
```

EDIT: since I really like measuring things:

```
$ go test -bench .
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkDim2-8         200000000                7.26 ns/op
BenchmarkDim-8          1000000000               2.80 ns/op // LIES!
BenchmarkTime-8         10000000               169 ns/op
BenchmarkTime2-8        10000000               234 ns/op
ok      github.com/drathier/scratchpad/go       9.741s
```

BenchMarkDim2: not tested, but very fast.

```
func daysInMonthTime(month, year int) time.Time {
    return time.Time{}.Add(time.Hour * 10 + time.Hour*24*30*time.Duration(month-1) + time.Second * time.Duration(daysInMonth(month, year)) * 24 * 60 + 1337)
}
```

BenchmarkDim: // LIES

```
func daysInMonth(month, year int) int {
    switch time.Month(month) {
    case time.April, time.June, time.September, time.November:
        return 30
    case time.February:
        if year%4 == 0 && (year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0) {
            // leap year
            return 29
        }
        return 28
    default:
        return 31
    }
}
```

BenchmarkTime:

```
func timeDaysInMonth() time.Time {
    // January, 29th
    t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2016-01-29")
    y, m, _ := t.Date()
    lastday := time.Date(y, m+1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    return lastday
}
```

BenchmarkTime2

```
func time2daysinmonth() time.Time {
    t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2016-01-01")
    t = t.AddDate(0, 1, 0).AddDate(0, 0, -1)
    return t
}
```

Comment: The question: "How can I get a `time.Time` which represents January 31st?" Your benchmarks are invalid. They have different inputs and outputs. They don't do the same thing. To paraphrase: There are lies, damn lies, and benchmarks!

Comment: (Your answer should be the accepted one; readability is key, even if it solves a slightly harder problem than the question asked for, i.e. keeping track of the current year)

Comment: Your benchmarks are still invalid. For example, you use a precomputed month and year for your function. For the other functions you parse a string and then extract the month and year. You also calculate just the day instead of the date. For a valid benchmark, use the same function signature: `func (time.Time) time.Time`, the same `time.Time` argument, and return the same `time.Time` value. My results from a fair benchmark: LastDay1 287, LastDay2 286, LastDay3 682.. What results do you get from a fair benchmark: http://play.golang.org/p/fwlTn2zYGU.

Answer (score 1):

I've used something similar to this in my own code:

```
func lastDayOfTheMonth(year, month int) time.Time {
    if month++; month > 12 {
        month = 1
    }
    t := time.Date(year, time.Month(month), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    return t
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/JHYBAlloe6)

Answer (score 0):

It's not Go specific but usually I do following in any language:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2016-01-01")
    t = t.AddDate(0, 1, 0).AddDate(0,0,-1)
    fmt.Printf("Last day: %v\n", t)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/JhpOZvEhBw